# Using Beautifulsoup in Python to iterate over non href links within an xml and retrieve specific information

Tags: python, html, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a python beginner and just started learning to crawl sites using Bsoup.

I'm trying to pull contact information (address, company name) from all the separate links on [this site](http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml).

Generally, I know how to retrieve a list of hrefs within typical html source, but since this is an xml, I've only been able to isolate the links to come out in the following format:

[u'http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/milano']

My code so far gives me all the company links in that format but I don't know how to make it go through each one and extract relevant information.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

resultsdict = {}
companyname = []
url1 = 'http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml'

html = requests.get(url1).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
# find the links to companies
company_menu = bs.find_all('loc')
for company in company_menu:
    print company.contents
```

From that list of links, it first needs to determine whether the page has contact info at all, and then if it does such as in [this example](http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/milano), then it should pull address/company name.

I believe the final information I'm looking for can be isolated by this div filter:

```
bs.find_all("div",{'style':'vertical-align:middle;'})
```

I've tried putting in a nested loop but I can't get it to work.

Any input is really appreciated!

Comment: Your for loop is returning a list containing one item. If you want to make a BeautifulSoup object out of the url contained within, use `BeautifulSoup(requests.get(company.contents[0]).text)`. My Italian isn't so good, so I can't really tell what you are trying to scrape from the resulting pages. - Edit: I got the code wrong the first time around, it should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use BeautifulSoup for this.  The site is returning perfectly valid XML that can be parsed with Python's included tools:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

req = requests.get('http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml')
root = et.fromstring(req.content)
for i in root:
    print i[0].text  # the <loc> text
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your request, you want lo get the url from a xml, but you are looking for css tags of formated xml... so wrong way.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url1 = 'http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml'

f = urllib2.urlopen(url1)

bs = BeautifulSoup(f)

for url in bs.findAll("loc"):
    print url.string
```

Mind i'm using findAll() method instead, and looking for "loc" tag, which contains the data you want to retrieve.

Comment: I've updated it to prove that it actually works ;)  Just copy and run the code...